# Open in a new window a document stored in SharePoint

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sharepoint

My problem is simple. From an aspx page, I need to open in a new window a document stored in Sharepoint.
To access the document in SharePoint I need to provide credentials.
To open the document in a new window, I need to use javascript.
=> how to link the two ?
here is the code :

```
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(strServerUrl);
        Web currentWeb = ctx.Web;

        ctx.Load(currentWeb);
        ctx.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Login", "Password", "Domain");

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        // Here I have access to SharePoint. 
        // I can download the document, but I just want to display it in a new window

        // something is missing here

        string strScript;
        strScript = "window.open('" + myUrltotheDocument + "','','width=800,height=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(myPanel, myPanel.GetType(), "ShowInfo", strScript, true);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
window.open(myUrltotheDocument",_blank","toolbar=no,menubar=0,status=0,copyhistory=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=1,location=0,Width=800,Height=800") ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the instruction to open the document in a new window... but the credentials are missing. On a local context the system will prompt for a login/password. When deployed on a server, it will result in an access error.

Comment: Try passing the credentials before loading the web.

Comment: I tried : the system prompt me for a login/password... as if it does not consider the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the only way I found to open the document in a new window from a .aspx page, is to download the document in a folder on the server, and then, to open a window in javascript with a link to the downloaded document.

```
Uri uriVar = new Uri(strDocUrl);

int intDirectoryIndex = uriVar.LocalPath.LastIndexOf("/");
string strFileName = uriVar.LocalPath.Substring(intDirectoryIndex + 1);

System.Net.WebClient wcVar = new System.Net.WebClient();
wcVar.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Login", "Pwd", "Domain");
string strPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/FileUpload/");
wcVar.DownloadFile(strDocUrl, strPath+strFileName);
string strLocalName = "FileUpload/" + strFileName;

string strScript;
strScript = "window.open('" + strLocalName + "','','width=800,height=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(myPanel, myPanel.GetType(), "ShowInfo", strScript, true);
```

I do not consider this as a "nice solution", but it does the job... If someone has a better one, please tell me.